# Uploading Unity Android App Bundle causing Google Play 64bit Non-Compliance Error, when worked previously

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

We have been uploading an app bundle to google play and it was compliant with the new 64 bit restrictions. (.aab) Now all of a sudden, with no changes to the project it is giving the error. https://gyazo.com/4988694e9f6ba5e5e5dde920e4c28199 This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement. - The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code. The project has ARMv7, ARM64 and x86 all selected. This error is coming from no where, because the app was compliant before... Does anyone know the solution? https://gyazo.com/ce2cec8d315ba365041edbf4b96a176b https://gyazo.com/40c4a781f107c840f2592cc8c299eb10

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by removing the x86 target